# Models created in alfresco are not displaying automatically when I add a document

Tags: alfresco

1)created models following the steps on alfresco site
2)Models not getting displayed when I  add a document (before saving it).
2)when I add a document -> go on edit properties -> All properties-> models not displayed.

Comment: What were the steps you exactly did, what documentation did you follow? Please follow the howtos and create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the types in share-config.xml. When u navigate to edit properties of a document u can find "Change Type" option, once you register your types in said xml, you can see a drop down of the type

```
<alfresco-config>
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
    <types>
        <type name="cm:content">
            <!-- Custom sub-type added for whitepapers -->
            <subtype name="my:whitepaper" />
        </type>
        <type name="cm:folder">
        </type>
        <type name="trx:transferTarget">
            <subtype name="trx:fileTransferTarget" />
        </type>
    </types>
   </config> 
</alfresco-config>
```

as mentioned [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/dev-extensions-content-models-tutorials-share-config.html)